# Python - Merge/update dictionary by smaller value

Tags: python

I would like to merge or update a dictionary in Python with new entries, but replace the values of entries whose key exists with the smaller of the values associated with the key in the existing entry and the new entry. For example:

Input:

```py
dict_A = {1:14, 2:15, 3:16, 4:17}, dict_B= {2:19, 3:9, 4:11, 5:13}
```

Expected output:

```py
{1:14, 2:15, 3:9, 4:11, 5:13}
```

I know it can be achieved with a loop iterating through the dictionaries while performing comparisons, but is there any simpler and faster ways or any helpful libraries to achieve this?

Comment: Why is a two or three line for loop not simple enough?

Comment: Any one-liners or libraries that would do this for you would still be using iteration, so its worth just writing it yourself with a loop

Comment: I do have large volume of data to deal with, so I would like to do it in a simpler and faster way

Comment: "Less code" does not mean "faster". There is no way to do this in Python without iterating.

Answer (score 1):

## Quick One-liner

```py
c = {**a, **b, **{key:min(a[key], b[key]) for key in set(a).intersection(set(b))} }
```

## Explanation

This should be quick enough because it uses the `set`.

You can merge dictionaries by using the `**dictionary` syntax like so: `{**a, **b}`. The `**` simply just "expands" out the dictionary into each individual item, with the last expanded dictionary overwriting any previous ones (so in `{**a, **b}`, any matching keys in `b` overwrite the value from `a`).

The first thing I do is load in all the values in `a` and `b` into the new dictionary:

```py
c = {**a, **b, ...
```

Then I use dictionary comprehension to generate a new dictionary, which only has the smallest value for every set of keys which are in both `a` and `b`.

```py
... {key:min(a[key], b[key]) for key in set(a).intersection(set(b))} ...
```

To get the set of keys which only exist in both `a` and `b`, I convert both dictionaries to `set`s (which converts them to sets of their keys) and use `intersection` to quickly find all keys which are in both sets.

```py
... set(a).intersection(set(b)) ...
```

Then I loop through each of the keys in the matching-keys set, and use the dictionary comprehension to generate a new dictionary with the current `key` and the `min` of both dictionaries' values for that `key`.

```py
... {key:min(a[key], b[key]) ...
```

Then I use the `**` syntax to "expand" this new generated dictionary with the expanded `a` and `b`, putting it last to make sure it overwrites any values from the two.

Works on the example given (ctrl-cv'd straight from my terminal):

```
>>> a = {1:14, 2:15, 3:16, 4:17}
>>> b = {2:19, 3:9, 4:11, 5:13}
>>> c = {**a, **b, **{key:min(a[key], b[key]) for key in set(a).intersection(set(b))} }
>>> c
{1: 14, 2: 15, 3: 9, 4: 11, 5: 13}
```

Comment: Weird, deleting my comment before cuz i cant reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you could easily use pandas to avoid writing the loop, though I dunno if there would be any speedup - didn't test that

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([dict_A, dict_B])
out =  df.min().to_dict()
```

output: `{1: 14.0, 2: 15.0, 3: 9.0, 4: 11.0, 5: 13.0}`

there's probably some edge cases you'd have to account for

Comment: Pandas seems a bit overkill?

Comment: I agree, but definitely more elegant and wouldnt be an import penalty if you're already using it elsewhere in your script. Wonder how it scales..

Comment: doesn't scale well, but no explicit loops. that's what the guy is asking for here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something short to do it. Not inherently the fastest or best way to do it, but figured I'd share nonetheless.

```
max_val = max(max(dict_A.values()), max(dict_B.values())) + 1 
keys = set(list(dict_A.keys()) + list(dict_B.keys()))
dict_C = { key : min(dict_A.get(key, max_val), dict_B.get(key, max_val)) for key in keys }
```

Comment: You can write `set(dict_A)` or `set(dict_A.keys())`, omitting `list()` entirely.

Comment: @shadowtalker because I'm merging the two lists of dict keys, and .keys() returns a dict_keys object (which you cannot merge with another dict_keys object), it's necessary to convert both to lists to join them.

Comment: Iterating over a `dict` iterates over its keys. `set()` iterates over its argument. Try it in a console.

Answer (score 0):

hello this is the code I have made Hope it's what you needed :

```
dict_A = {1:14, 2:15, 3:16, 4:17}
dict_B= {2:19, 3:9, 4:11, 5:13}
dict_res =dict_B

dict_A_keys = dict_A.keys()
dict_B_keys = dict_B.keys()

for e in dict_A_keys :
    if e in dict_B_keys :
        if dict_A[e]>dict_B[e]:
            dict_res[e]=dict_B[e]
        else:
            dict_res[e]=dict_A[e]
    else:
        dict_res[e]=dict_A[e]
```

I have tested it and the output is :

```
{1: 14, 2: 15, 3: 9, 4: 11, 5: 13}
```